# construction of a sequence of smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider $r>0$ , $1<p< \infty $. Consider $K $ a compact set in $R^n$ with $K \subset B(x_0 , r)$.

Define

$$ B = \{ u \in C^{\infty}_{0}(B(x_0 , r)) ; u=1 \ on \ K ,  0 \leq u \leq 1\}$$

$$ A= \{ u \in C^{\infty}_{0}(B(x_0 , r)) ; u=1  \ \textit{in a open neighborhood of K } \}$$

A natural question is :

given $u \in  B$ , exists a sequence $v_n \subset A$ with $v_n \rightarrow u$ in $H^{1,p}( B(x_0 , r))$ ?

I tried to prove this fact , but nothing...  I draw a picture and I belive the result is true. Someone can give me a help ?If i prove the affirmation , then I understand a theorem in the book that i am studying.

thanks in advance =)

Comment: Are $C_o^\infty$ compactly supported smooth functions? Also what's $H^{1,p}$?

Comment: About $C^{\infty}_{0}$ you're right. and $H^{1,p} $ is the classical Sobolev space

Comment: Ohh, waay out of my league, sorry :)

Comment: @Timkinsella ok =)